# Why does Mail.app keep sent attachments open?

Tags: mail.app, attachments

Sending a pdf as an attachement leaves open the original file according to
`lsof | grep my.pdf`
How can i prevent this rather unpleasant behavior ?

OSX 10.6.8 - Mail Version 4.6 (1085)

UPDATE:
I filed a bug at apple and the guys at apple actually responded saying this is a know bug (duplicate of #4023875) which is still open.

Comment: How long after mail activity finishes are these file handles kept open?

Comment: at least an hour

Comment: Well - I can't imagine any network access still being pending at that point. Likely you found a bug.

Comment: How are you sending the file?  Simple attachment, drag and drop type, or from within preview or another pdf reader?

Comment: I attach the file using the UI-Dialog in Mail

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Version 4.6 (1085)

Comment: so by UI Dialog you mean you are clicking on the attachment icon.....??  Or are you actually using a jQuery call for it.

Comment: jap, the paperclip icon

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for why anything Apple has done, but three things come to mind for changing the open file status:

- file a bug http://bugreporter.apple.com
- quit mail
- patch the Mail program to fix the bug

Unless you have some third party Mail plug in, it seems you've identified something that hopefully Mail eventually releases since you might have problems deleting a file that's still open.